# Multi-process Class is not storing data in the actual process

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have made the following example of a larger piece of code I'm writing. I would like multiple processes to manage 100 or so threads which are also classes.

I have two problems, one is that the "add" method doesnt seem to actually be adding to the new process. The other is that even though 2, 3, or 4 processes get created, the threads are all still started under the first, main, process.

The following code doesnt show the threaded class, but maybe if you can help explain why the process isnt adding correctly I can figure out the thread part.

```
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing

class manager(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.symbols_list = []

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print "Process list: " + str(self.symbols_list)
            sleep(5)

    def add(self, symbol):
        print "adding..." + str(symbol)
        self.symbols_list.append(symbol)
        print "after adding: " + str(self.symbols_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = manager()
    m.start()
    while True:
        m.add("xyz")
        raw_input()
```

The output is as follows:

```
adding...xyz
after adding: ['xyz']
Process list: []

adding...xyz
after adding: ['xyz', 'xyz']

adding...xyz
after adding: ['xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz']
Process list: []
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new process, the child one inherits the parent's memory but it has its own copy.

Therefore changes on one process won't be visible on the other one.

To share data within processes the most recommended approach is using a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

In your case, you might want to take a look at [how to share data within processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Be aware that it is a bit more tricky than synchronising the processes via Queues or Pipes.